# Setting current url in a custom xamarin forms web view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm starting with `Xamarin.Forms` and what I'm trying to do is simply setting a `CurrentUrl` property on a custom `Webview` in `Xamarin.Forms`

In other words: When `OnPageFinished` method is called, I need to set the `CurrentUrl` property of `MyWebView` to the new Url.

Anyone have an idea?

Here's my main `Webview`:

```
public class MyWebView: Xamarin.Forms.WebView
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "CurrentUrl",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string CurrentUrl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And here's my `Renderer` in `Project.Droid`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyProject.Droid.WebViewRenderer))]
namespace Manateq.Droid
{
    public class WebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer
    {
        public WebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {

            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new Callback(Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity));
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            MyWebView myWebView = sender as MyWebView;
            if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentUrl")
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public class Callback : WebViewClient
    {
        Activity _context;
        public Callback(Activity _context)
        {
            this._context = _context;
        }
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            //view.LoadUrl(url);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));
            _context.StartActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Show();
        }
        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            //element.CurrentUrl = url;
            DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's I'm using the custom web view in `xaml`:

```
<customControls:MyWebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="webView"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by `Leon` is good. But I found an easier way to do it. Here's what I've done.

In the `Callback` class that extends `WebviewClient` I've edited `OnPageStarted` and `OnPageFinished` to be as following:

```
public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
{
    DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Show();
    base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    var args = new WebNavigatingEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url }, url);
    _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigating(args);
}
public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
{
    DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Dismiss();
    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url };
    var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, url, WebNavigationResult.Success);
    _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
}
```

As for `_rendered` its: `ElementController => Element;` and it exist in the `WebViewRenderer` class.

When adding these line of codes, the `Navigated` event is being hit normally. So when that happens we can simply use the `url` parameter that exist in `Navigated` event.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can got the value of CurrentUrl by `MyWebView myWebView = e.NewElement as MyWebView; var currentUrl=myWebView.CurrentUrl;` in `OnElementChanged`; Then you can transfer this value to Callback's constructor. In the end, you can set it in the `OnPageFinished` method by  `element.CurrentUrl = currenturl;` like following code.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(WebViewRenderer))]
namespace WebviewDemo.Droid
{
    public class WebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer
    {
        public WebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
           
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
          
            MyWebView myWebView = e.NewElement as MyWebView;
            var currentUrl=myWebView.CurrentUrl;
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new Callback(Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, currentUrl));
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            MyWebView myWebView = sender as MyWebView;
            if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentUrl")
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public class Callback : WebViewClient
    {
        Activity _context;
        string currenturl;
        public Callback(Activity _context,string currenturl)
        {
            this._context = _context;
            this.currenturl = currenturl;
        }
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            //view.LoadUrl(url);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));
            _context.StartActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Show();
        }
        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            element.CurrentUrl = currenturl;
            DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you want to achieve the result like this GIF?

[image]

If so, you can load the current url in the `OnPageFinished` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;
using WebviewDemo;
using WebviewDemo.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(WebViewRenderer))]
namespace WebviewDemo.Droid
{
    public class WebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer
    {
        public WebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
           
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
          
            MyWebView myWebView = e.NewElement as MyWebView;
            var currentUrl=myWebView.CurrentUrl;
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new Callback(Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, currentUrl));
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            MyWebView myWebView = sender as MyWebView;
            if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentUrl")
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public class Callback : WebViewClient
    {
        Activity _context;
        string currenturl;
        
        public Callback(Activity _context,string currenturl)
        {
            this._context = _context;
            this.currenturl = currenturl;
        }


        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            //if (!loadingFinished)
            //{
            //    redirect = true;
            //}

            //loadingFinished = false;
            //view.LoadUrl(currenturl);
            //Console.WriteLine("Loading web view...");
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
           
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            
            if (url.Equals("https://www.google.com/"))
            {
                view.LoadUrl(currenturl);
            }
           
        }

        //public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        //{
        //    //view.LoadUrl(url);

        //    //   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));
        //    //  _context.StartActivity(i);

        //    view.LoadUrl(url);
        //    isRedirected = true;
        //    return true;
        //}

        //public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        //{
        //    base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        //    if (!isRedirected)
        //    {
        //        //Do something you want when starts loading
        //    }

        //    isRedirected = false;
        //    // DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Show();
        //}
        //public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        //{
        //    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        //    if (!isRedirected)
        //    {
        //        //Do something you want when finished loading 
               
        //    }
           
        //   // element.CurrentUrl = currenturl;
        //  //  DependencyService.Get<ILoadingIndicator>().Dismiss();
        //}
    }
}
```

In the xaml. You can bind the value for CurrentUrl, Or just set it directly.

```
 <customControls:MyWebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="webView"/>
```

Xaml background code.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
               webView.Source = "https://www.google.com";
             webView.CurrentUrl = "https://www.baidu.com";
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how did you get the `element` entity in `element.CurrentUrl = currenturl;`??

Comment: One other thing, I thing some binding need to be added to `xaml` file right? In order to bind the `CurrentUrl` property on the `Webview` url

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish I update my answer, you can refer to it.