# WebView with Custom Renderer always shows up blank screen in Android Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Custom Renderer to enable download and zoom options when a WebView is opened in Xamarin, but even seeting the Source with a URL parameter, the page shows empty screen. What to do?

My WebView.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:loading="clr-namespace:MPS.Libertas.Mobile.Styles.Frames"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MPS.Libertas.Mobile.Behaviors"
             x:Class="MPS.Libertas.Mobile.Views.DetalhesDoProcesso.PecasPJe"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E6E8EA" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <WebView x:Name="wvPecasPJe" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                Navigated="PagOnNavigated"
                Navigating="PagOnNavigating"
                 Source="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   
                 />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And code setting the Source value behind:

```
 private UrlWebViewSource _Value;
        public UrlWebViewSource Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set
            {
                if (_Value != value)
                {
                    _Value = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
                }
            }
        }
 
public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;
            try
            {
                if (navigationData is string linkPecasPJe)
                {
                    Value = new UrlWebViewSource
                    {
                        Url = $"{linkPecasPJe}"
                    };

                    Console.WriteLine(Value);
                                   
                }

                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Não foi possível recuperar o link das peças.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DialogService.ShowError(ex, "Erro ao abrir as peças do PJe!", "Voltar", null);
                await NavigationService.NavigateToPrevious();
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
                await base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
            }
        }
```

My CustomRenderer:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Webkit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.IO;
using System;
using MPS.Libertas.Mobile.Droid.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebView))]
namespace MPS.Libertas.Mobile.Droid.Renderers
{
    internal class MyWebView : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                var webView = new global::Android.Webkit.WebView(this.Context);
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;
                webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetDownloadListener(new CustomDownloadListener());
                this.SetNativeControl(webView);
                var source = e.NewElement.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
                if (source != null)
                {
                    webView.LoadUrl(source.Url);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class CustomDownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
    {
        public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
        {
            try
            {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
                // if this path is not create, we can create it.
                string thmblibrary = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory + "/download";
                if (!Directory.Exists(thmblibrary))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(thmblibrary);
                request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Android.App.Application.Context, FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "download");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.DownloadService);
                dm.Enqueue(request);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that, in the CustomRenderer, the source keeps loading with a null value. But the page should load even then because I am setting the source in the ViewModel, shouldnt it?

Comment: Have you verified that the page (set in ViewModel) becomes visible, if you DON'T use your custom renderer?

Comment: Did you try to set the source in the xaml directly to check if the webview will render correctly?

Comment: Yes, if I dont use the custom renderer the page becomes visible. Also if I set the source directly to the webview it will render correctly as well. The OnElementChanged method on the custom renderer gets fired BEFORE the source is set in the Initialize Async method in my webview, so it creates a web view without a source, I think. But seeting the source in that method is the only way to pick a URL parameter that I sent through another web page also.

Comment: You said setting the source directly to the webview it will render correctly. So the cause should be the binding. Where did you set the binding context?

Comment: In the Initialize Async method above, setting the Value variable. Also setting the Source this way works and the web view is rendered if I don't use the custom renderer.

Comment: You can refer to [this answer about android webview custom renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63391376/17455524), and use the e.NewElement instead of the this.SetNativeControl(webView);.